# What is my Switch IP?

Tags: networking, ip, switch

I struggle low network performance. When I copy a file to one server to another server, the network speed up to 8 Gb/s. I think that this issue can be missing switch configuration. How can I learn switch IP?

Comment: What kind of switch? (And what kind of network? Ethernet? Infiniband?)

Comment: `Fibre Channel Switch (Connectrix)` that's a SAN switch made by Dell/EMC, not a network (Ethernet) switch. What kind of environment are we talking about here? Please be MUCH more detailed. What kind of Fibre Channel HBAs are in your server(s) and what kind of storage system (disk array) do you have? Do they even support speeds higher than 8Gbps?

Comment: @StarCat to be fair, the 'N' in 'SAN' stands for 'Network'

Comment: But @StarCat you're right. This is wrong switch. I'm looking for correct switch linked with  network device  now. This is a complicated network and I can't give more details. I think that more information is not necessary. Thanks for quick response. Just, can you tell me about how can I learn switch IP? Is there a simple command like traceroute for IP?

Comment: Ethernet Switch (1U, 10GbE, 48 port)

Comment: So you're looking at 10 Gbps max, not 32 Gbps... What OS are the servers running? For Ethernet, LLDP would be an option, but it's not always enabled, and how to receive LLDP information depends on the OS. (Did nobody _document_ the switch management IPs? Is there no sticker on the switch itself?)

Comment: @u1686_grawity, *to be fair, the 'N' in 'SAN' stands for 'Network'* – 
u1686_grawity. Of course, but since the question is not about FC SAN  but about IP networking and server-to-server copying, it's not the most obvious part of the equation.

Comment: Can make bond configuration on this switch ?

Comment: How would we know? You didn't even tell us what kind of switch it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not really any common "trace" mechanism for Ethernet. (Some such mechanisms kind of exist, like 802.1ag OAM trace, but they're *really rare* in practice – and more importantly, they don't tell you the IP address anyway, they only tell you the *MAC* address, because that's what switches work with.)

What you *can* get is the address of the switch that's directly connected to you (i.e. the 1st L2 hop only). Most enterprise Ethernet switches support LLDP for that purpose – although it is not always *enabled*, and even when it's enabled not all switches actually include the "Management IP" field, but it's still the closest you can get.

On a Linux server, use `lldpctl` if lldpd installed; otherwise `ladvdc` if ladvd is installed; otherwise start a packet capture with `tcpdump -e -v -n -i eth0 "ether proto 0x88cc"` and wait a few minutes for the periodic LLDP broadcast to show up.

On a Windows server, you could run [LDWin](https://github.com/chall32/LDWin) or do a packet capture either with pktmon ([instructions](https://alanjmcf.wordpress.com/2022/04/15/lldp-cdp-on-windows-with-no-extra-software/)) or Wireshark (the same `ether proto 0x88cc` capture filter).

Finally, keep in mind that not all Ethernet switches have IP addresses in the first place. IP is not part of the core functionality of a switch – it is for management and configuration only – and even in enterprise networks you can encounter fully unmanaged switches that do not offer any configuration.

Comment: The switch might also have been configured with a separate VLAN (and subnet) for configuration.